# Can't resolve DatabaseReference

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am trying to initialized db connection but it crash everytime i lunch the app

here is the Error:

```
                                                                --------- beginning of crash
                          05-12 20:58:14.279 10772-10772/qu.easycookproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: qu.easycookproject, PID: 10772
                                                                java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzUU()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/qu.easycookproject-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes17.dex)
                                                                    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                    at qu.easycookproject.FireApp.onCreate(FireApp.java:16)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1012)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4553)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1364)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here in mainActivity

```
 db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cook");
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
      FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog , BlogViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(
       Blog.class,
       R.layout.indivi_row,
       BlogViewHolder.class,
       db

     ) {
   @Override
   protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {
       viewHolder.setTitle (model.getTitle());
       viewHolder.setDesc (model.getDesc());

   }
```

};

```
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Dependencies :

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.0'
```

and FireApp

```
   public class FireApp extends Application {
   public void onCreate()
    {
    super.onCreate();
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    }
   }
```

Plz if anyone can help me with this error i ll be thankfull

Comment: Did you add the google-services.json?

Comment: yes I did , i also checked the pkg name and all these stuff are matching

Comment: try re-doing all the steps. It can be a dependency issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both the legacy SDK and new SDK:

```
// legacy
Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

// new
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("cook");
```

This is not good practice and is likely the source of the problem.

You should use the new SDK exclusively. Remove this line from your build dependencies and update your code:

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```

The [Upgrade Guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android) is helpful.

You must also use the same version for all Firebase libs.  Change `firebase-messaging` to 10.2.0.

And also take care to use a version of FirebaseUI that is compatible with the Firebase libs used.  For Firebase libs 10.2.1, use FirebaseUI 1.2.0.